# How to set default transition with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, transition

I'm using jquery mobile and I would like to set default transition to `slidefade`
How can I do that with jquery mobile?

Maybe something as `$.mobile.`

Comment: Use `$.mobile.changePage('file.html');` instead of `window.location`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this **before** you load jQuery Mobile:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
  $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slidefade";
}
```

Comment: after that I can normally use this redirection in the code `window.location.href="list.html";` and it should bind this transition to it?

Comment: I don't see that transition...it just shows the page normally

Comment: Try using just `slide` instead of `slidefade`

Comment: just did and still nothing...are you sure about this method?

Comment: Strange, it should work. Take a look at **[this](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/api/globalconfig.html)**

Comment: Make sure your setting this before you load jQuery mobile, as I noted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35465/discussion-between-shivam-and-user123-456)

Comment: It's either slide or fade.

Comment: You should mark this correct by the way because it answers your question correctly. Your problem itself is different then the question.